# Wait for delete link to load with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Using `ruby on rails 5.2.3` I have a delete link as follows:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', [:microposts, micropost], data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
```

I am testing it using the following code in a feature spec (with metadata js: true)

```
  page.accept_confirm do
    click_link 'Delete'
  end
```

This works intermittently. When it fails, it gives an error

```
Rack app error handling request { GET /microposts/lessons/16 }
#<AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'show' could not be found for Microposts::LessonsController>
```

i.e. instead of a delete request, there is a get request.  It seems that the link is being clicked, but the data-method=delete has not yet loaded. How do I wait for the link to be properly loaded before clicking on it.

Comment: It's not possible, as you suggest, that the link is clicked before data-method=delete is loaded. It looks as if the link that's being clicked is not the one you intend. The link you intend has an href specified by [:microposts, micropost], but the get request is going to /microposts/lessons/16, they seem to be inconsistent. Maybe the intended page was not yet loaded? Verify this by doing (e.g.) page.find('h1',text: 'expected heading').

Comment: The Lesson model uses STI to inherit from the micropost model, and in this case the micropost is of type lesson, so the request should be to ```delete /microposts/lessons/16```. I do check that I am on the correct page. Why do you think it is impossible that the link can be clicked before the data-method=delete is loaded. My understanding is that in rails, the delete is done by using javascript to modify a get link.

Comment: typically rails/ujs, which includes the http delete hack, is included in application.js, which is loaded into a web page's <head> element, and therefore loads before any of the page elements. The ActionView link_to helper creates a <form> to submit with the method=_delete attribute, rendered by the server, so it's on the page when the <a> element appears.

Comment: That makes sense, though I would have thought that it is possible that the javascript for the delete hack is loaded first but for some reason does not fire. When I get the chance I will investigate further to see if I can be more specific about what is not working. Unfortunately for this conversation thread but fortunately for me, this intermittent failure has stopped happening, so I will have to wait for a reappearance before progressing further.